# How can i imitate DJI's Lightbridge system

Tags: dji-sdk

I would like to know all of Lightbridge, Phantom 4 Pro, Inspiron 2's controller and drones communication method.

I have many drones from DJI including Phantom 4 Pro, Inspire 2, and Matrice 100.
I want to create a Lightbridge system that is mounted inside the controller through PC programming.
Because the DJI drones I purchased connect the mobile device and the controller with USB cable, and the controller and the drone communicate with the Lightbridge, so the controller must be in the middle of the communication system, but I just want to control the drones directly through my PC.

**As a result, how can I imitate the Lightbridge system to communicate with my PC, control (takeoff,landing etc.) , and capture live images.**

So I'd like to know about the Lightbridge that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lightbride is a proprietary protocol. That means we (I work at DJI) do not disclose or document the details of its implementation.

On another hand, removing the remote controller would mean you create/provide your own transmitter which add quite a lot of complexity.

The best way for you to control the aircraft from the PC at this point is to write a mobile app as a bridge and control the app through your PC.

Now, this can be done in a wired manner:

You could write an Android app with the mobile SDK on a device with ethernet such as Odroid and chain it all together.